# Create all possible dataframes using always one row of n other dataframes in a list

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe that is split into a list by its id, as shown below. Now I'd like to create a list of dataframes of all possible combinations always using only one row of each dataframe in the list. I've already experimented with `expand.grid` and `combn` in an `lapply` call using `names(data)` to index the dataframes, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Using the `iris` dataset here's a short example:

```
library(dplyr)

# data
iris %>%
  select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,round,0) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  split(.,.$Species)

# This is what you get
$`setosa`
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species
1            5           4  setosa
2            5           3  setosa
3            4           3  setosa
4            6           4  setosa
5            4           2  setosa

$versicolor
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width    Species
6             7           3 versicolor
7             6           3 versicolor
8             6           2 versicolor
9             5           2 versicolor
10            5           3 versicolor

$virginica
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width   Species
11            6           3 virginica
12            7           3 virginica
13            8           3 virginica
14            5           2 virginica
15            7           2 virginica
16            7           4 virginica
17            6           2 virginica
18            8           4 virginica
```

And now I want to get all possible dataframes, always using one line of each dataframe in the list above like:

```
$[[1]]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species
1            5           4 setosa
6            7           3 versicolor
11           6           3 virginica

$[[2]]...
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I would try to do something with purrr's reduce and tidyr's crossing function: `data_split<- 
   iris %>%
   select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species) %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric,round,0) %>%
   distinct() %>%
   split(.,.$Species) 

reduce(data_split,crossing)
`

This should give you a dataframe with all the combinations. They are in a wide format though so you will have to do some more data wranging. does that help?

Comment: It's a good start, but it doesn't produce the expected output such as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be probably a better way to do this but one way using base R where it should work for any number of groups is

```
#Find all possible combinations of row indices for each list
row_combns <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(lst, function(x) seq(nrow(x))))

#Make one big dataframe combining all possible combination subsetting 
#it from corresponding list element
df1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(lst), 
               function(x) lst[[x]][row_combns[[x]], ]))

#Create a grouping index
df1$index <- seq_len(nrow(row_combns))
#Use the index to split
split(df1, df1$index)

#.....
#$`199`
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width    Species index
#4.39             6           4     setosa   199
#10.38            5           3 versicolor   199
#18.23            8           4  virginica   199

#$`200`
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width    Species index
#5.39             4           2     setosa   200
#10.39            5           3 versicolor   200
#18.24            8           4  virginica   200
```

where `lst` is

```
lst <- iris %>%
         select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species) %>%
         mutate_if(is.numeric,round,0) %>%
         distinct() %>%
         split(., .$Species)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# update data
iris %>%
  select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,round,0) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) -> iris_upd

iris_upd %>%
  split(.,.$Species) %>%               # split by species column
  reduce(crossing) %>%                 # create all row combinations
  group_nest(id = row_number()) %>%    # group by row id
  mutate(d = map(data, ~{d = data.frame(t(matrix(., nrow=3, ncol=ncol(iris_upd))))  # reshape data
                         names(d) = names(iris_upd)                                 # set column mnames
                         d})) -> iris_comb
```

Now the dataset `iris_comb` has a column d that contains all combinations that you want:

```
iris_comb$d

# .....
#
# [[199]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width    Species
# 1            4           2     setosa
# 2            5           3 versicolor
# 3            6           2  virginica
# 
# [[200]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width    Species
# 1            4           2     setosa
# 2            5           3 versicolor
# 3            8           4  virginica
```